What's the most idiomatic word or phrase for the address that you refer visitors to?
My bilingual dictionary suggests "visiting address" for the address that you refer visitors to, as opposed to a postal address, but I haven't been able to confirm this in any monolingual dictionary (Cambridge, Longman, Merriam-Webster, Collins), nor do I get any hits on Google, other than page after page with hits from companies in Sweden, Norway and the Netherlands (even though I'm only searching the UK domain) – i.e. hits from non-native speakers of English. So – what would be the idiomatic word or phrase in BrE?

Why do you think that just 'address' (one word) would not be suitable?

In English-speaking countries it's highly unusual for 'the address that you refer visitors to' to be different from one's postal address, so there is no need for such an expression.

In our community we would give a STREET ADDRESS to visitors who need to find our houses - as our mail goes to post boxes situated on the outskirts of the village.

If there was any doubt you'd give specific instructions like "When you arrive, ring the doorbell on number 44" or "All visitors should go to the side door/gatehouse/security booth." Or these days a postal code (e.g. for the car park) or what3words code. If you give what's obviously an address it's seldom necessary to tell people that it's an address, or you can say: "car park: address" or "public entrance: address". (While a place usually has one address, there could be separate entrances for e.g. employees, deliveries, tradespeople, and visitors/customers.)

@MichaelHarvey Good question! Because we make the distinction in my own language? :) Seriously though, with companies, organisations, and the like, there's often one address that you go to when you want to visit, and another that the post goes to, right? But, I guess it's enough that we have a separate phrase for one of them rather than for both (i.e. "postal address" (or "mailing address" in AmE)).

@KateBunting Really? Huh – I didn't know that! In my country I'd say it's more common than not that companies, organisations, etc. have one postal and one "visiting" address.

@RonaldSole Ah, that makes so much sense!!! Thank you!

Helen, you didn't make it clear that you were thinking of companies. You just asked about 'the address that you refer visitors to'. Since most people here are not businesses, I think we assumed you were talking about home, or residential addresses. Of course a UK business, especially a big one, may have a correspondence address, a delivery address, an office address for visitors, and for legal purposes, a registered address, etc. There are buildings in big cities that act as 'mailing' or 'accommodation' addresses for many small companies or people.

You didn't specify that you were talking about companies and not private individuals! In that case I would agree with what Stuart says.

@MichaelHarvey My bad! Apologies for that! I guess this is a great example of how one's own language influences thinking – since in my language we'd never ever use the word meaning 'visiting address' for private addresses, it never even occurred to me that I'd have to specify this! But of course, since the concept as such doesn't really seem to exist among native speakers of English (or at least not saliently enough to have its own word), I really should have specified it! I'm sorry for the confusion ...

@KateBunting Yes, sorry about that! Like I just wrote to MichaelHarvey, it just didn't occur to me that I'd have to specify that, which was, of course, a mistake on my part, based on my own preconceptions!

"visiting address" is not an idiomatic phrase in English.

what is the word or phrase for the address that you refer visitors to

That would be "address".
When forced to distinguish it might be "physical address".
You may provide visitors with "directions" which are instructions for how to arrive at the "address".  Depending on the context, "directions" is a common word and often appropriate.  "Drive two blocks south, then turn left, it's the third house on the right, a blue two-story house."  That sort of thing.
In American English, what you are calling "postal address" is a "mailing address". Usually the "mailing address" and the "physical address" are the same.  If they are different, you'd provide a "mailing address", while the "physical address" would still be the "address".
